# Should hie.yaml be stored in Git?

Tags: haskell

If you are using the [`haskell-language-server`](https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with your editor, it is sometimes necessary to generate a `hie.yaml` file, usually by running [`gen-hie`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/implicit-hie).

Should the `hie.yaml` file be kept in Git (or whatever CM system you are using)? It isn't necessary for the build, and it includes an opinion on whether you are using `stack` or `cabal` to build with, which other developers might not agree with. But on the other hand not including it means that every developer needs to keep regenerating it if it changes, and it may not always be exactly what `gen-hie` produces.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd say that if you need something other than the implicit cradle you should add it to Git. This issue is for supporting both Cabal and Stack with a single file: <https://github.com/haskell/hie-bios/issues/199>.